# Problem when unit-testing the stop method of my RMI Server

Tags: java, junit, rmi

I have implemented a RMI Server and now I wanted to test if the method to start and stop this server are correcly implemented, using a JUnit test.

Here is the (simplified) code of my RMI server:

```
public void startServer() {
    try {
        ...
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(serverPort);
        registry.rebind("foobar", myRemoteObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}

public void stopServer() {
    try {
        registry.unbind("foobar");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make a JUnit test to check if the `startServer()` and `stopServer()` are correctly working.

Thus, I've implemented this simple JUnit test:

```
private boolean isRunning(int port) {
    boolean portTaken = false;
    ServerSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new ServerSocket(port);
        // If we have succesfully created the ServerSocket, then it means that the port is available...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        portTaken = true;
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            }
        }
    }
    return portTaken;
}

@Test
public void testStartAndStopServer() {
    MyRMIServer server = new MyRMIServer();
    assertNotNull(server);
    int port = server.getServerPort();
    assertTrue(port != -1);
    // Check if the current server is NOT running.
    assertFalse(isRunning(port));
    // Start the server and then check if it is running.
    server.startServer();
    assertTrue(isRunning(port));
    // Now stop the server...
    server.stopServer();
    assertFalse(isRunning(port));
}
```

My problem is that the last assert is not valid. If I print the stacktrace in the method `isRunning()`, I get the error `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`.

This means that the port is still used so I guess that my `stopServer()` is not correct. What did I get wrong?

Note that if I use the `registry.list()` method before and after calling my method `stopServer()`, I see:

```
BEFORE: foobar
AFTER: (nothing)
```

---

Edit:

I've also modified my `stopServer()` regarding a solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241034/how-to-remotely-shutdown-a-java-rmi-server):

```
public void stopServer() {
    try {
        registry.unbind("foobar");
        UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(myRemoteObject, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't solve my problem...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up modifying my server code so that the start method would basically look like (notice the call to `getRegistry` and `rebind` *after* the catch which will get back the registry if it was already there):

```
public void startServer() {
    try {
        ...
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(serverPort);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
    LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
    registry.rebind("foobar", myRemoteObject);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would tend to avoid empty exception blocks, even in "can't happen" cases.

```
  try {
            socket.close();
  } catch (IOException e2) {
  }
```

just concenvably there's an exception there.

My (rather wild) guess, is that you might have a timing problem. Perhaps the network infrastructure takes a short time to notice that the socket is closed. Does sleeping for a second or two before the final assert fix it?

Comment: 1. Yes, in my complete code, no exception block is empty ;) It was just to simplify code here.
2. I've tried to put a Thread.sleep(upTo5000ms) just after server.stopServer();, but it does not help :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to unexport the registry. Try:

```
public void stopServer() {
    try {
        registry.unbind("foobar");
        UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, [one source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/210114/Distributed-Java/java/Shut-down-RMI-Registry) claims you cannot free up the port until the JVM exits. I don't know if that's true or not (haven't tried it), but unexporting the registry is a step in the right direction.